# intellij 14: how to hide excluded search results?

Tags: intellij-idea

say i search in my project for

`log.`

now it finds 900 occurrences in some folders like 3rd party libraries.

I can select the folders and hit delete to exclude them.

But, when pressing expand all, it will still expand the 100 folders. I don't want to see those results at all, that's why I excluded them.

in eclipse this was very easy, but seems very hard in intellij. E.g. I want the excluded search results to be hidden / disappear completely.

**EDIT:**
say I want to search in the folders

models, controllers, config, test, migrations, lan

but not in all other folders.

And of the models folder, only certain subfolders.

What is wrong with intellij? it seems impossible to do it

Comment: I think you should provide a proper search scope to exclude those files, it will also increase the search speed. Selecting for example `Custom: Project Files` or `Directory`

Comment: the search speed really isn't the problem. Having to select custom search scopes and thus maybe doing a mistake, is a much bigger issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this plugin:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7833

Though I have not tested it on my own it might solve the issue. The description of the plugin might be misleading regarding "usages" - as this term is used in other context as well... but I found it at this Youtrack issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-22996

As it seems this issue got recently updated with a "Fixed in build..." state - nevertheless I don't understand why it is a Teamcity build id and not an IDEA one.

Comment: Just a thought ... but instead of just downvoting it could be helpful to as well comment with -1 *because...*

Comment: seems to work fine for me in 14.1 i can remove search results, and if i the press replace all, only visible results are replaced

Comment: Great! I need to give it a try on my own when I am back at my workstation

Comment: it is just super ineffective in remove the results. If I remove many results, my intellij freezes for a good couple minutes... That plugin is badly written. But it is ok for most uses i reckon